# Можно ли получить массив зон Яндекс Карт с помощью запроса?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, typescript, yandex-maps-jsapi, yandex-geocoding-api

Я делаю с командой сайт по доставке еды. Стоит задача отрисовывать карту по такому примеру:

[Ссылка на доку](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/delivery_zones)

Как можно увидеть в примере - данные какие зоны доставки надо отрисовать берутся с файла data.geojson
Я бы хотел, что при изменении моей карты в конструкторе карт - карта менялась сразу и на сайте. Сейчас я вынужден хардкодить данные с этого файла путём ручного импорта с конструктора карт.
Говоря иначе - я бы хотел исключить момент импорта данных с карт и добавления их в БД / на сайт хардкодом.

Кто-то меняет карту -> К ней делается запрос (каждый раз при заходе на сайт и отрисовке карты) -> С запроса к нам приходит JSON -> Мы отрисовываем карту.

Официальный запрос к тех. поддержке дал примерно следующий ответ:

> Здравствуйте!
>
> Спасибо за проявленный интерес к нашему сервису! Вашу задачу можно
> выполнить на основе API Яндекс.Карт . Всю необходимую информацию и
> пошаговые инструкции по отображению полнофункциональной карты вы
> можете найти на страницах документации к JS API . Здесь же вы сможете
> найти примеры реализации типовых задач. Вы можете экспортировать зоны
> из Конструктора и загрузить их на карту, как в этом примере.
>
> Пример с зонами доставки также есть в Песочнице.
>
> Если в процессе разработки будут возникать вопросы по реализации ваших
> идей, вы всегда можете обратиться за их решением на Stack Overflow.
> При создании вопроса обязательно укажите метку нужного API — так
> эксперты сервиса смогут быстрее ответить, а другим пользователям будет
> проще найти ответ.

Есть ли способ избежать ручное обновление данных с карты?

Answer (score 1):

Если даже поддержка сказала, что данные с карт [Конструктора](https://yandex.ru/map-constructor/) ни запросом, ни по API не получить, значит стоит для новой разработки следует использовать документированные методы [JS API](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/).
Поскольку даже если вы найдёте какое-то решение, эксплуатирующее недокументированные возможности или баг,вы потратите время зря, когда эта "дыра" будет закрыта.

В **JS API** же есть возможность рисовать необходимые геометрические примитивы. В том числе [полигоны](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/polygonEditor). Отрисовывайте полигоны в собственной версии редактора, сохраняйте их данные у себя и обращайтесь к полученному файлу напрямую из кода, минуя работу в отдельном продукте, который пока не видно, чтобы сколь-нибудь значимо развивался (я о Конструкторе).